# Why tee writes to file content different from what it shows in console

Tags: linux, unix, shell, alpine-linux

I need to redirect all the output from cli app in alpine container to both - console and file, and then exit with that app exit code.

As I have to use sh - I have found this solution on stack:

```
mkfifo pipe 
tee resultfile.txt < pipe &
myapp > pipe
```

I have modified it to

```
mkfifo pipe
tee resultfile.txt < pipe &
myapp 2>&1 > pipe
```

So now as a result I see everything logged in console, but resultfile.txt has only one stream recorded (dunno if out or err).

I thought that after I redirect myapp output from err to out with 2>&1 everything is always in one stream - but it does not look like it. Can you please point out where the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

Order of stream redirection matters. This:

```
myapp 2>&1 > pipe
```

will:

1. Redirect file 2 (stderr) to file 1 (stdout).
2. Redirect stdout (overwritten by stderr) to file `pipe`.

Use this instead:

```
myapp > pipe 2>&1
```